# What is "=~" operator meaning in Ruby code

Tags: ruby

Could you please explain me about the **=~** operator in this ruby code? Is it equivalent as "match"

```
def method_missing(method_name, *argument, &block)
  if method_name.to_s =~ /user_(.*)/
    user.send($1, *argument, &block)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

thanks

Comment: Yes. [ReadTheDocs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E)

Comment: @cricket_007 It’s actually [String#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E).

Comment: @Gumbo, whoops, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

There's a subtle difference between `match` and `=~`. `match` returns a `MatchData` object  describing the match. However `=~` returns the index of the first match. They both return `nil` if no
match found.

I strongly recommend you to go through the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html).

Comment: It’s actually [String#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) since `to_s` returns a String object.